# Module has no attribute "celery" when using Django 1.7.1, Python 3.4 and Celery 3.1

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

My project is using Python 3.4, Django 1.7.1, Celery 3.1. I have RabbitMQ running as expected.

The project structure is the out-of-the-box standard:

```
my_project/
    my_project/
        settings.py
        celery.py
        ...
```

I know there are a couple of duplicate questions, but they're not resolving the issue for me. My celery.py file is as follows:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import django

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings


# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings')
django.setup()

app = Celery('my_project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Settings:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
```

When I try to run:

```
$ celery -A my_project worker -l debug
```

I get the celery attribute error.

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.1.17', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery-3.1.17-py3.4.egg/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery-3.1.17-py3.4.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery-3.1.17-py3.4.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery-3.1.17-py3.4.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 305, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery-3.1.17-py3.4.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 465, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery-3.1.17-py3.4.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 485, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery-3.1.17-py3.4.egg/celery/app/utils.py", line 240, in find_app
    found = sym.celery
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: couldn't you put this line `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` inside this file `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery-3.1.17-py3.4.egg/celery/app/utils.py` on the line 240 (before `found = sym.celery`) to see what module it actually found? this looks very much like it could be a PATH error --> perhapse your PATH or PYTHONPATH variables point to your outer directory, or to another place altogether. Make sure the `sym.__file__` points to the package (directory) that contains your `celery.py` file

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice from the traceback that Celery doesn't seem to be respecting my virtualenv, which is activated when I attempt to start the workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an installation problem. I just reset my virtualenv, re-installed celery and viola. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

Your config is fine. But when start the worker, you need to specify the app name or the file which has the celery object. But you are just specifying the `my_project` which doesn't have the celery object.

```
celery worker -A my_project.celery -l debug
```

should solve the problem.

Also rename your celery.py to celery_conf.py or something else.

Comment: Ok, now a different error: `ImportError: No module named 'django'` Why is Celery looking in /usr/local/bin instead of Celery in my virtualenv?

Comment: Looks like I may have an installation issue. Re-installing.